# Can I use Tensorflow and Keras interchangeably?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

I am using l2_regularization 
Tensorflow has - tf.nn.l2_loss 
Can I use this?

1. K.sum(K.square(K.abs(Weights)))
2. tf.nn.l2_loss

Can I use this interchangeably in Keras (Tensorflow backend)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but keep in mind that `tf.nn.l2_loss` computes `output = sum(t ** 2) / 2` (from documentation), so you've forgotten about multiplying by `0.5`. Also you don't have to calculate `K.abs(weights)` because `K.square(K.abs(weights)) == K.square(weights)`.

The differences are:

- `tf.nn.l2_loss` is implemented directly in [kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/kernels/l2loss_op.h).
- operations in Keras backend translate directly to Tensorflow defined [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py).